# Rendering local images from database

Tags: react-native, react-image

I'm making a country picker with flags. The country names and flag image name is coming from database, like this (sample):

```
dataSource: [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Afghanistan",
  image: '../assets/flags/af.png'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Bahrain",
  image: '../assets/flags/ba.png'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Canada",
  image: '../assets/flags/ca.png'
}]
```

Then I send that dataSource to my component

```
                        <CountryPickerFlags
                          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                        />
```

Then in the component FlatList (renderItem) I do:

```
  _renderItemListValues(item, index) {
      var image_uri = {uri: item.image} ;   
      
      console.log(JSON.stringify(image_uri));
        
    return (
    
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={1}
        style={styles.listRowClickTouchStyle}
        onPress={() => this._setSelectedIndex(item.id, item.name)}
      >
        <View style={[styles.listRowContainerStyle,{ flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}]} >
          <Image source={image_uri} />
          <Text style={styles.listTextViewStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

But the flag is not rendered....
If I hardcode the image (with require) it's working...

```
  <Image source={require("../assets/flags/af.png")} />
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `assets` folder and create a file `prepareImages.js` and paste inside the following:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const files = fs.readdirSync("./assets/flags").filter(x => x.includes("png"));
const ex = "{\n" +
files.map(x => `"../assets/flags/${x}": require("./${x}"),`).join("\n") + "}";
const res = "export default " + ex;
fs.writeFileSync("./assets/flags/index.js", res);
```

This will create an `index.js` file where will be an object like that:

```
"../assets/flags/af.png": require("./af.png"),
```

Import images from this file where you render `Image` component.

```
import images from "../assets/flags/images";
```

Render image source like that:

```
<Image source={images[image_uri]} />
```

Comment: How do I "execute" the prepareImages.js ?

Comment: Go to assets folder and run **node prepareImages.js**

Comment: Thanks! Worked! But with this system you propose me, how do I merge the data from database, with this images import to send it to the component... The component will be shared so I cannot import there the images...

Comment: I don’t understand what you want to do

Comment: I did it....dataSource: [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Afghanistan",
  image: images['../assets/flags/af.png']
},

Comment: Good. You can remove prepareImages.js

Answer (score 0):

Add require to your data set like

```
dataSource: [ { ..., image: require('../assets/flags/af.png')}]
```

Comment: yes, but teorically the dataSource comes from DB, should I put "require" also in the database?

Comment: Yes, If you put require in the prefix, It would help here to show the image on render