# How to import data images from json file

Tags: javascript, json, image, react-native, expo

I'm using expo react-native. I want to store all my images in one file and from there import it to my components when I need, I just don't know how to write it.

Right now I used in Clumsy and complicated and unreadable way like this:

Constant file "Images" to hold all the pictures:

```
     export const t1 = require("../assets/images/t1.jpg");
     export const t2 = require("../assets/images/t2.jpg");
     export const t3 = require("../assets/images/t3.jpg");
     export const t4 = require("../assets/images/t4.jpg");
     export const s1 = require("../assets/images/s1.jpg");
     export const s2 = require("../assets/images/s2.jpg");
     export const s3 = require("../assets/images/s3.jpg");
     export const s4 = require("../assets/images/s4.jpg");
     export const r1 = require("../assets/images/r1.jpg");
```

and from each component that i need the images I just import it:

```
   import { t1, t2, t3, t4 } from "./Images";
    ...
    <Image source={t1} ..........
```

It works great, but I want to know how to save the constant images in json file I understand that is more efficient way to hold the images

Thanks a lot

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354887/rendering-local-images-from-database/65356580#65356580).

Comment: :/ no helped for me..

Comment: What was wrong? Can I help you?

Comment: Its not what im asked for. I just need to declare constant json file with all my images

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a variable that holds all your img like this

```
  const t1 = require("../assets/images/t1.jpg");
  const t2 = require("../assets/images/t2.jpg");
  const t3 = require("../assets/images/t3.jpg");
  const t4 = require("../assets/images/t4.jpg");
  const s1 = require("../assets/images/s1.jpg");
  const s2 = require("../assets/images/s2.jpg");
  const s3 = require("../assets/images/s3.jpg");
  const s4 = require("../assets/images/s4.jpg");
  const r1 = require("../assets/images/r1.jpg");

  export = {t1, t2, t3, t4, s1,s2,s3,s4,r1};
```

so you can import it like this

```
import img from "./Images";

<Image source={img.t1} ..........
```

is that what you want buddy?

Answer (score 0):

try to import image like this

```
import t1 from '../assets/images/t1.jpg'
import t2 from '../assets/images/t2.jpg'
```